# Math.round(Math.random()) combination seems to be generating too many 0's in my javascript programme

Tags: javascript, math

I am trying to make a really simple script to generate a 2d array in which every nth array does not contain it's own index as an element but contains a random amount of other randomised index values as their elements and can not be empty. The following is a little code I wrote to attempt to achieve this:

```
totElList = []
numEls = 1000

for (i=0;i<numEls;i++) {
    totElList[i] = []
    for (j=0;j<numEls;j++) {
        totElList[i][j] = j
    }
}

for (i in totElList) {
    totsplice = Math.round(Math.random()*(numEls-1))
    totElList[i].splice(i,1)
    for (j=0;j<totsplice;j++) {
        rand = Math.round(Math.random()*totElList[i].length)
        while (typeof(totElList[i][rand]) === undefined) {rand = Math.round(Math.random()*totElList[i].length)}
        totElList[i].splice(rand,1)
    }
}
```

The problem is when I run this the totElList array seems to contain more 0's than any other number even though I assumed elements would be removed at random. I did a test to confirm this. The amount of 0's is always the maximum out of all possible values for a given numEls. I am guessing this is something to do with the workings of Math.random() and Math.round() but I am unsure. Could somebody please give me some insight? Thank you.

Comment: pleade add a working example. actually it runs forever.

Comment: instead of `Math.round`, take `Math.floor` which works better for indices, because it is zero based.

Comment: You could reduce numEls if it is running slow for you. I see what you mean with Math.floor though that works like a charm thank you. I guess it was just a simple number problem that was confusing me.. not the first time.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of [`Math.round`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round), take [`Math.floor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor) which works better for indices, because it is zero based.

> Example with one digit and a factor of 2 as index for an array with length of 2.
>
> As you see, the second half index is moved to the next index of every number, which results into a wrong index and with the greatest random value, you get an index outside of the wanted length.
>
> ```
> value  round  floor  comment for round
> -----  -----  -----  -----------------
>  0.0     0      0
>  0.1     0      0
>  0.2     0      0
>  0.3     0      0
>  0.4     0      0
>  0.5     1      0    wrong index
>  0.6     1      0    wrong index
>  0.7     1      0    wrong index
>  0.8     1      0    wrong index
>  0.9     1      0    wrong index
>  1.0     1      1
>  1.1     1      1
>  1.2     1      1
>  1.3     1      1
>  1.4     1      1
>  1.5     2      1    wrong index
>  1.6     2      1    wrong index
>  1.7     2      1    wrong index
>  1.8     2      1    wrong index
>  1.9     2      1    wrong index
> ```